# Is viscosity directly connected to non-superfluid component?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

I am having questions when considering the microscopic models of superfluid BEC. In weakly interacting dilute alkali gas BECs, there are ways to introduce normal fluids without reducing the condensate fraction. I was wondering if any shear/bulk viscosity is going to emerge in these circumstances? E.g. if a rotating bucket experiment would be appropriate to measure the superfluidity?

Comment: Absence of shear viscosity is usually considered the sine qua non of superfluidity.